# Spark WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window Operation Moving all data to a single partition this can cause serious performance degradation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Getting the above mentioned WARN message, and performance issue, while using the following SQL Spark transformation

```
val sqlstr = """SELECT * FROM (
SELECT AC.*, ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_TYPE, CATEGORY_CODE, PROCESS_CAT ORDER BY GEO_LOC DESC) AS RowNum FROM Account AC)
WHERE RowNum = 1"""

val acct_sel_df = sqlContext.sql(sqlstr)
```

Running Spark 2.1, Scala and spark sql.

The above statement will result in the data frame acct_sel_df.  This
   is transformed from the Account dataframe (which was registered as
   temp view using `Account.createOrReplaceTempView("Account")`.

Is there a way to specify partition in the source or resulting data frame? Will that avoid moving data to a single partition?

The number of partitions could be found in advance by querying the source data frame. Without this there is a serious performance hit.

Comment: Do you know why  `PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_TYPE, CATEGORY_CODE, PROCESS_CAT` is just single partition, do they have a single value across?